# How do I use 2 libraries with same external symbols?

Tags: c++, openssl, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-c

I have 2 libraries in my project - MySQL C++ Connector and OpenSSL library for sockets, and as I think MySQL library already has OpenSSL functions inside.

[Errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH95h.png)

Errors I get (in text format):

```
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-x509_d2.obj) : error LNK2005: X509_STORE_load_locations already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-ct_policy.obj) : error LNK2005: CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_free already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-ct_policy.obj) : error LNK2005: CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_cert already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-ct_policy.obj) : error LNK2005: CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_issuer already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-ct_policy.obj) : error LNK2005: CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_shared_CTLOG_STORE already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-ct_policy.obj) : error LNK2005: CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_time already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_Calc_A already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_Calc_server_key already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_Verify_A_mod_N already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_Verify_B_mod_N already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_check_known_gN_param already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-srp_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: SRP_get_default_gN already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_INFO_free already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_INFO_get0_CERT already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_INFO_get0_NAME already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_INFO_get_type already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_close already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_eof already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_error already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_load already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
1>libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-store_lib.obj) : error LNK2005: OSSL_STORE_open already defined in mysqlcppconn-static.lib(libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
```

My project include directories:

```
\asio-1.24.0\include
\openssl\Lib\x64\Release\include
\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc
```

Linker input:

```
\openssl\Lib\x64\Release\lib\libcrypto.lib
\openssl\Lib\x64\Release\lib\libssl.lib
crypt32.lib
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

Comment: It'll work much better if you upload all pictures and photos to Twitter or Facebook instead. They are designed for that. Stackoverflow is designed for asking questions ***in plain text***, that can be copy/pasted for research. Can you remove all images and replace them with plain text?

Comment: Have you tried not linking with libssl at all and rely on the symbols fomr mysqlcppcon-static.lib. Otherwise maybe you could get away with this by including your ssl header files in a namespace. And then using that namespace throughout your code. Just a theoretical idea that might work (not done it myself yet).

Comment: @PepijnKramer If I only leave mysql library, then linker says this

`2>server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_set0_tmp_dh_pkey`

Comment: It looks like `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` is a static library. It should be rebuilt as a shared library (that will be, presumably, named just `mysqlcppconn`) that also gets linked with `libssl`. Static and shared libraries cannot be mixed like that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you please write this to the answer, I just included `mysqlcppcon.lib` which was in the same folder with `mysqlcppcon-static.lib` and everything compiled! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static and shared libraries cannot be mixed like that.

`mysqlcppconn-static` is statically linked with libssl, and attempting to link, again, with libssl is not going to work.

`mysqlcppconn-static` is meant to be used with special-purpose applications that get statically linked only with mysql, and so they can be distributed without the mysql and openssl libraries.

Whenever multiple libraries are involved the only practical approach is to link only with shared libraries.